# Force install I want to call API service

Tags: android

when I force uninstall I want to call API service to pass a value for my application.so can you tell me how to fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An app can't know when it's removed. Other apps can use [ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED).